# Tennis matches input representation for ANNs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a list of tennis matches with information like time, court, surface, rank of winner/loser, winner/loser games won in set etc. I plan to train a MLP network with this information (using PyBrain) and map it to a single output —— 1.0 if first player is winner, 0.0 otherwise. The goal is to forecast future matches (where some of the input will be undefined).

Each player is identified by an integer. There are over 100 players. I wonder if I can represent the players directly with these integers, if I should use a decimal (i.e. divide by 100) or if I should use a binary representation? Will it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if it would matter how the player numbers are represented.

I am assuming that the Neural Network would be trained on the time, court, surface, rank etc. and not on the player number, so the Player ID would likely be independent of the algorithm.

It sounds like you have a data structure that contains the players and their historical performance and rank, as well as a timetable of matches.  So it is likely that the player and timetable information would be fed in as parameters of the Neural Network, but the Player ID would be an external parameter that governs the evaluation process.  If this is true, then how this is implemented depends on your evaluation algorithm and not so much the Neural Network.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking the player id could affect the result, by making the network represent which players have defeated whom earlier. But perhaps this is not such a good idea and I should use only the match stats -- seems like that's the way it's been done in similar scenarios.